# Linear differential equation with varying coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(x^2+1)y'' + xy' - y=0$ by using one particular solution.

I have no problem solving the equation once I have the particular solution, but I don't understand how I am supposed to find it. The textbook says to try either look for a particular solution of the form $y_1 = e^{ax}$ or $y_1 = x^n + ax^{n-1} +\ldots $

We have: $$y'' + \frac{x}{x^2+1}y' -\frac{1}{x^2+1}y =0$$
Let's try $y_1 = e^{ax}$, then

$$a^2e^{ax} + \frac{x}{x^2+1}ae^{ax} -\frac{1}{x^2+1}e^{ax} = 0$$ and

$$e^{ax}\left (a^2 +\frac{x}{x^2+1}a - \frac{1}{x^2+1}\right )=0$$
Giving us $(x^2+1)a^2 + ax-1 = 0$. Is this useable? Aren't we supposed to get a fixed constant not something that depends on $x$?

How would you decide in which form you would look for the particular solution and why?

Comment: The second recommendation is actually much better :) why didn't you check this form?

Comment: how exactly do I determine which power should I be using? $x^2 + ax + b$ or $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ or further than that? The book is very vague giving explanation as to what this means. The examples provided are simple and conviniently give results, which doesn't help.

Comment: If you plug in $x^n + \dots $ into the LHS of your equation, what's the leading term of resulting polynomial?

Comment: What does LHS stand for?
$(n-1)nx^{n-2} + \frac{x}{x^2+1}nx^{n-1} -\frac{1}{x^2+1}x^n = 0$

Comment: make the ansatz $$y(x)=C(x)x$$

Comment: LHS mean "left-hand side" (of equation) :) highest order term in this case is $x^n$ and it has coefficient $-1+ n + n(n-1)$. Do you see why? Now you understand what value of $n$ we should take?

Comment: Do we equate $n(n-1)+n-1$ to zero? So that would be $(n-1)(n+1)$, $n=1, n=-1$

Comment: What did you do with the x-terms? Do we just disregard them or have I mis-understood?

Comment: No, we don't disregard them. First we check what happens if we just plug polynomial into the LHS. We find its highest order term and its coefficient. If that polynomial is solution, then LHS is identically zero polynomial and all its coefficients are zero, including the coefficient that correspond to the highest order term. And from here we get the equation for $n$ :)

Comment: I agree the highest order term is $x^n$, but I don't agree its coefficient is $-1+n+n(n-1)$, these are the partial coefficients of the summands. I don't understand this pseudo-science, could you please illustrate your explanation?

Comment: Easy, @AlvinLepik . If you address something to particular person, don't forget to mention that person. And if you don't understand something, don't call explanations of other people "pseudoscience". The explanation is brief but it is concrete and quite rigorous. What are your arguments that this is the wrong expression for coefficient?

Comment: My apologies, Evgeny, I was quite upset with this assignment and the textbook which offered no help in solving it.

Comment: If we look for a solution in a polynomial form, we arrive at $(n-1)nx^{n-2}+\frac{x}{x^2+1}nx^{n-1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}x^n = 0$. You say that the coefficient of the highest order term is $n(n-1) +n-1$, but all I see is $-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. I don't understand how you came to the conclusion you have.

Comment: No problems. You've forgot to mention me in comment again :) yeah, now I understand why you have problem understanding me: I considered the very first equation without dividing it by $1+x^2$. And I plugged polynomial directly into it.